# jQuery ajax error but the server is responding fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make request to server using jQuery `ajax()` but onResponse error block is being executed . The server response is working fine when the request is done from any other resources. This is my ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: url,
    data:{adminname: admin.ADMIN_NAME, adminID: admin.ADMIN_ID, modulename: moduleName },
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        alert("hello world");            
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error) {
        //when the response is returned this is being displayed
       alert("error");
    }

});
```

The request is being sent and even the data is being is updated but when the response is returned error block is being executed. There no errors on the server side. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whats does the error code and message say?

Comment: i tried but I am not able to print it ! it says undefined

Comment: I think that you should **test** using the real path instead of *url*

Comment: I doesnt make any difference

Comment: Your server might respond with a http `200` but it can still mean there is no proper error handling set up. Debug server side to see what error you get

Comment: I debbuged the server side i checked everything there's no error the response is in json i even printed that out

Comment: Undefined error? This sounds weird. Maybe you can share the headers section from the network tab of your dev tools.

Comment: This can happen if the server responds with a 200 OK, but the response is not correctly formatted JSON. Check exactly what the responseText is in the network tab of the console

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133884/discussion-on-question-by-jois-jquery-ajax-error-but-the-server-is-responding-fi).